# Issue with google spreadsheets function

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have the following in a cell(I3)

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),,IF(ISBLANK(I3),,TimeStamp()))
```

However it keeps giving me a circular dependency error

It calls a timestamp function when b3 is selected, however at current when that is reloaded by someone else the data is reloaded(including the function).  What I would like essentially is only to call the timestamp function if b3 is filled and I3 isn't.  If I3 is filled I would like it to ignore the timestamp call as it already has a timestamp.

Comment: I'd advise having this in a separate cell, say J3.

Comment: Kind of a workaround which I knew about but was seeing if there was something I Could have done to eliminate unnecessary columns.  In any case it currently sits like this just hidden.

Comment: Actually never mind this workaround has the same issue as the original in that now two columns repopulate time data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I had to use google script to detect if the cell had value already and then populate it with data based on what value it had.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the value you're trying to populate (cell I3) is, itself, in the formula.  I.e. the cell is referring to itself, which is why you have a circular reference.

Comment: I understand the problem, just looking for a solution.